# VBA: Worksheet Change causes multiple copied and pasted data

Tags: vba

Currently, I have columns from A to AB. I want to achieve a result such that if any cell is updated in Columns Y:AB of a row, the cells (Column A and Y:AB of a row) will be copied and pasted into a new sheet called  Sheet2 into columns A to E.

My code currently can do the above but when I change all 4 values one by one in Columns Y to AB, 4 rows will be generated reflecting each change that was made. E.g. First row to be copied reflects the change made in Column Y. Second row copied reflects the change made in Column Z. Third row copied reflects the change made in Column AB. And so on.

I just need one row copied onto Sheet 2 that reflects all changes made in Columns Y to AB of a row in Sheet 1. Is there a way to do so?

I am not familiar with VBA and all guidance are much appreciated! Thank you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Columns("Y:AB")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Range("Y" & Target.Row, "AB" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("A" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Let's clear this out. So if a row recently change is already copied in Sheet2, you don't need to copy it again but update it somehow? For example, I update Y2, so that row will be copied. Then I update Y4, it will be copied. What happens when I change Z2? Will it be copied or will the recent data copied when I change Y2 be updated?

Comment: The recent data copied when you change Y2 be updated! Thanks!

Comment: Is the sequence of changing the 4 values fixed? i.e the first change happens in Y col and last change in AB col. And all 4 value would be changed? or 3/2/1 value could be changed for a row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    With sh1
        If Intersect(Target, .Range("Y:AB")) Is Nothing Then GoTo forward
        Dim trow As Long, drow As Long, rng As Range
        trow = Target.Row
        Set rng = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(.Range("A" & trow).Value, sh2.Range("A1"))
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            drow = sh2.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            sh2.Range("A" & drow) = .Range("A" & trow)
        Else
            drow = rng.Row
        End If
        .Range("Y" & trow, "AB" & trow).Copy sh2.Range("B" & drow)
    End With
forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume forward
End Sub
```

I assumed *Column A* contains unique identifier. 
So above code does what you describe and what you explained in your comment. HTH.